# PHP, MySQL select all if

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement

I have problem with PHP and MySQL please help..

```
$lokalita_s = $_POST['lokalita_s'];

$query = "SELECT nazov, lokalita FROM reality WHERE lokalita = '".$lokalita_s."' ORDER BY id";
```

............
But if ($lokalita_s == "nezáleží")... then i want to select every thing from database..
something like this :

```
$query = "SELECT nazov, lokalita FROM reality ORDER BY id";
```

............

This is not working :

```
$lokalita_s = 0;
$lokalita_s = NULL;
$lokalita_s = *;
```

I really dont want to use it like if else.. because i want to use more variables in that query and it won't be effective

Comment: So why don't you have 2 separate queries then?

Comment: Because i want use later more variables.. which can have different values.. and than i would have 50 if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$lokalita_s = $_POST['lokalita_s'];
$wherClause = null;

if($lokalita_s != "nezáleží") {
   $wherClause = "WHERE lokalita = '" . $lokalita_s . "'";
}

$query = "SELECT nazov, lokalita FROM reality $wherClause ORDER BY id";
```

Comment: Nope.. :/ 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\reality\search.php on line 7..

Comment: My bad, there were extra braces for if. Try now and tell me how it goes.

Comment: lol, I must go to bed now, Make sure you are using updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines? (This works in Oracle)

```
$lokalita_s = $_POST['lokalita_s'];

$query = "
SELECT nazov, lokalita FROM reality WHERE lokalita = '". $lokalita_s."'
UNION 
select nazov,lokalita from reality where '". $lokalita_s. "' = 'nezáleží'
order by id
"
```